# Unable to inject mocks for my jersey project

Tags: java, junit, mockito, jersey

I'm very new to writing unit tests for java. I want to write a test for method1:

```
public ClassA {
   public String method1() {
      ClassB classInst = ClassB.getInstance()
      return classInst.doSomething()
   }
}
```

Here, doSomething in classB connects to some databases and does an operation. This is my test class:

```
public TestClassA {
   @Mock
   private ClassB classBInst = mock(ClassB.class)

   @InjectMocks
   private ClassA classAInst = new ClassA()

   @Before
   public void setup() {
      when(classInst.isClientEnabled()).thenReturn("ReturnStr");
   }

   @Test
   public void testMethod1() {
      String result = classAInst.method1();
      assertEquals(result, "ReturnStr")
   }

}
```

But the assert is failing because ClassB.doSomething() is not returning the mocked return value. Am I doing something wrong here? What is the correct way to mock classB here? I am using junit4 and mockito here

Comment: How  `ClassB` looks like?

Comment: In class A, you dare calling a `static` method to get your instance of ClassB, so `InjectMocks` won’t help you with that.  What you want to do instead is described here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito

Comment: Oh okay. So I should use powerMockito for this?

Comment: No, powermockito is old - mockito has been extended to mock static methods, as described in that answer, or here for more details : https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods

Comment: Instead of “old”, rather PowerMockito has issues with Junit5.  Best to stick with pure Mockito where possible (including the mocking of static methods)

Comment: Consider making your class more test-friendly. Instead of reaching for the singleton instance of ClassB, you could store it as a field - preferably initialized in a constructor